# Speeding up CUPS + Gutenprint

Tags: printing, printer, cups

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian Lite and a printer connected to it. It is controlled by CUPS with Gutenprint drivers.

This configuration is working very slow, it takes about 7 seconds to print a 10x10px image and bigger images take up to 15 seconds.

On a Windows machine, printing is almost instantaneous, so it's not a printer problem.

`Top` shows that `rastertogutenprint` occupies about 100% of CPU during the print.

Is it any way to speed up the print? Any tips or directions would be valuable.